# Zoom turns image white?

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I'm doing some live video processing on iOS with OpenCV.

I do a couple of things to the image, first I inspect it and draw some overlays, then I zoom it by a factor of two.

In `processImage`, if I do just the first step, it's all fine, but if I add a call to my function `zoom` it makes the image appear very white and translucent:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
static void resizeLock_(cv::Mat &img, int rows, int cols){
    cv::Size newSize;
    newSize.width = cols;
    newSize.height = rows;
    cv::resize(img, img, newSize,0, 0, CV_INTER_AREA);
}

static void zoom(cv::Mat &img, int ratio){
    cv::Size originalSize = img.size();
    resizeLock_(img,img.rows*ratio,img.cols*ratio);
    double c = ((double)ratio -1)/(double)2;
    img(cv::Rect(cvRound(originalSize.width*c),cvRound(originalSize.height*c),originalSize.width,originalSize.height)).copyTo(img);
}
```

...

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{
    doProcessing(image);
    // if the next call is omitted, image looks fine.
    zoom(image,2);
}
```

Comment: Can copyTo use the same cv::Mat as input and output (last line in zoom)?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Copying to a temporary Mat instead makes no difference.

Comment: Is the output correct if you *only* call `zoom()`? I can't reproduce your results with version 2.4.3.2 on iOS 6.

Comment: @Aurelius It still happens only with the zoom code.